# Get the title of the image (not just the title of the a)

Tags: jquery, fancybox

first thing I have to say: I'm really new to JQuery and Javascript, so forgive me if it's a stupid question.

My problem with fancybox is this: When the plugin put the "a title" under the image shown I need the "img title" too, but I have no idea of how to do it :/

I hope someone can help me (and please explain it to me like if I were reeeeeally stupid :D)

Comment: Show use some HTML. Edit your question, paste it in, highlight it and press the "{}" button.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but the `title` attribute on an anchor `<a />`, is what shows up and will override whatever you have in the `title` tag of the `<img />` element, if you're creating an anchor around an image. Unfortunately there's no default way to show both.  Trying to nest `title` attrs, your browser will only display the one at the top level.

Although you *can* apply the `title` attribute to most HTML elements, by no means should you. If you have longer descriptive text for an image beyond what's acceptable for `alt`, you should include it in using the `longdesc` attribute.